# List Collection Class

Tags: c#

Hello let me describe i don't have any errors in my code , i am just asking a very basic question here RELATED TO list collection class let see i have a class called customer

```
class customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string  Name { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
    }
```

in my main method i created an array of customer and initialize those properties that is present in my customer class

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            customer[] customers = new customer[3];
            customers[0] = new customer
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "A",
                Salary = 30000
            };
            customers[1]=new customer
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = " B",
                Salary = 50000
            };
            customers[2] = new customer
            {
                Id = 3,
                Name = "C",
                Salary = 90000
            };
            List<customer> Cust= new List<customer>(2);
            Cust.Add(customers[0]);
            Cust.Add(customers[1]);
            Cust.Add(customers[2]);
            for (int i = 0; i < Cust.Count; i++)
            {
                customer C = Cust[i];
                Console.WriteLine("Id = {0} & Name = {1} & Salary = {2}",C.Id,C.Name,C.Salary);
            }
                Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

Okay! so this code is working so perfectly nice , but my question is that at last  we created a list called **cust** and add all the custemers in to it , so why is it necessary to make another object with type customer as i did in for loop

```
customer C = Cust[i];
```

why can i don't call my code like this

```
console.WriteLine{Cust[i]}
```

As far as i know when we create object of the class than we can easily acces the code inside that class with that instance variable . so why not here?

Comment: You realize you have this typo, right? `Cuss.Add(customers[0]);`

Comment: sorry this is typing prob ignore it

Comment: Are you asking why you needed to write this line of code? `customer C = Cust[i];`

Comment: @NicholasV. exactly

Comment: You don't need that line, you can just say `Console.WriteLine("Id = {0} & Name = {1} & Salary = {2}",Cust[i].Id,Cust[i].Name,Cust[i].Salary);`

Comment: You cannot `do Console.WriteLine(cust[i])` because WriteLine doesnt accept a customer object. It wants a string, or a string formattable arg list

Comment: @NicholasV. - while what you said is technically true, creating the reference adds to readability and maintainability. However, IMO foreach is more appropriate here anyway.

Comment: @NicholasV. thankyou got it now (y) :)

Comment: @Colin, I hear you. I was just answering his specific question so that he knew. I like creating the reference as well.

Comment: @pm100 yeah but what i actually was trying to say that why we create a new object, instead of using the existing one, cust[i].Id solved it .. thanks to nicholas

Comment: @faizan Take note of the `ForEach` statement Colin mentions. When possible, it's recommended to use it... more clarity in your code and easier to code.

Comment: @NicholasV. yeah Thankyou

Comment: @pm100 No, Console.WriteLine WILL accept a `customer` object, but it will call the `ToString()` method of the object. So you only need to override `ToString()` to make this work.

Answer (score 3):

In your for loop, you're not *creating* a new customer, you're just creating a reference to the existing one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Cust.Count; i++)
{
    customer C = Cust[i]; //<- not new, just a reference to the customer at index
    Console.WriteLine("Id = {0} & Name = {1} & Salary = {2}",C.Id,C.Name,C.Salary);
}
```

A more concise way to loop is to use foreach instead of for (NOTE: using C# 6.0 string interpolation):

```
foreach(var c in Cust)
    Console.WriteLine($"Id = {c.Id} & Name = {c.Name} & Salary = {c.Salary}");
```

Comment: You must also mention that you are using C#6 syntax of string interpolation.

Comment: I added that comment, because you're right that in might confuse someone new to C#.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you were asking to do, you would first need to override the `ToString()` method on your class. The `ToString()` method will be called implicitly by `Console.WriteLine`:

```
class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Id = {0} & Name = {1} & Salary = {2}", Id, Name, Salary);
    }
}
```

Now that you have a default way to represent a customer as a string, you can do exactly what you were asking to do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Cust.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Cust[i]);
}
```

And, now that you have this, you can do it in an even easier way. The following will implicitly pass each item to `Console.WriteLine()`, which will call the item's `ToString()` method:

```
customers.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

If for some reason you DON'T want to override the `ToString` method, you can still access the instance properties using the index without creating a new object, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Cust.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Id = {0} & Name = {1} & Salary = {2}",
        Cust[i].Id, Cust[i].Name, Cust[i].Salary);
}
```